# Find the middle element from a single link?

Tags: java, mysql, max, iso

I have this problem:

> Find the middle element from a single link list without continuing the number of node (if number of node is odd then one middle element,if even then two middle element).

Comment: What did you try before asking?

Comment: `max`, `iso`, `mysql`--what are those tags here stand for?

Comment: I Dont know how to post it.. So i wrote what was in example

Comment: if it is your homework also try something, feel free to post a question if you  occur any programming issue (of course, while it's not duplicate or another assignment)   Edit: do you have any code? Post it also.

Comment: I don't now how to post it.so what was in the example I wrote(tag)

Comment: Only body is the question..nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Supposing `Node` is a class keeping next node and a value:

```
Object returnMiddle(Node first) {
   Node n, m;
   n = m = first;
   while (n != null) {
      n = n.next;
      n = (n == null ? null : n.next);
      m = (n == null ? m : m.next);
   }
   return m.value;
}
```

Idea is simple: making two steps on `n` you make only one step on `m`, so when `n` reaches the end, `m` will point to the middle node.